# Do not want to submit form until email and phone are validated - Vue.js 3

Tags: regex, forms, vue.js, validation, vuejs3

I have a form that I am validating - all fields are required. Everything seems to be working except my form submits even when an incorrect phone and email are entered (according to my regex Watch validation). What do I seem to be missing to make sure that the default refresh is prevented if the email and phone are entered incorrectly?

First section is my html form, the second is my Vue.js 3 app code.

```html
<form name="mainForm" @submit="submitForm" method="post">
  <div class="row mb-3 gx-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="form-label aw-font-freight-medium mb-0"
        >First Name*</label
      >
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstname"
        class="form-control aw-font-freight-medium aw-firstname"
        v-model="contact.firstName"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="form-label aw-font-freight-medium mb-0"
        >Last Name*</label
      >
      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastname"
        class="form-control aw-font-freight-medium"
        v-model="contact.lastName"
        required
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="form-label aw-font-freight-medium mb-0"
        >Email Address *</label
      >
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        class="form-control aw-font-freight-medium"
        v-model="contact.email"
        required
      />
      <small class="form-text text-danger" v-if="msg.email"
        >{{msg.email}}</small
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3 gx-2">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="form-label aw-font-freight-medium mb-0"
        >Phone*</label
      >
      <input
        type="text"
        name="phone"
        class="form-control aw-font-freight-medium"
        v-model="contact.phone"
        required
      />
      <small class="form-text text-danger" v-if="msg.phone"
        >{{msg.phone}}</small
      >
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <button type="submit" class="btn aw-bg-orange text-light">
      <strong>Download</strong>
    </button></a
  >

  <div>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">
      <em>* Denotes a required field.</em>
    </small>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
      now: new Date().toISOString(),
      isSubmitted: false,
      msg: [],
      contact: {
        firstName: "##firstname##",
        lastName: "##lastname##",
        email: "##email##",
        phone: "##phone##",
        address: "##address##",
        city: "##city##",
        state: "##state##",
        zip: "##zip##",
        checked: false,
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    contact: {
      handler(newContact) {
        this.validateEmail(newContact.email);
        this.validatePhone(newContact.phone);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(e) {
      const isValid =
        this.contact.firstName ||
        this.contact.lastName ||
        this.contact.email ||
        this.contact.phone;
      if (!isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    validateEmail(value) {
      if (
        /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20})$/.test(
          value
        )
      ) {
        this.msg["email"] = "";
      } else {
        this.msg["email"] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
      }
    },
    validatePhone(value) {
      if (
        /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im.test(
          value
        )
      ) {
        this.msg["phone"] = "";
      } else {
        this.msg["phone"] = "Please enter a valid, 10 digit phone number.";
      }
    },
  },
});

app.mount("#awApp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `isValid` is not working as you expect

```js
const isValid =
  this.contact.firstName ||
  this.contact.lastName ||
  this.contact.email ||
  this.contact.phone;
```

The value of `isValid`  will return `##firstname##`

You should use `&&` instead of `||` to make sure all values are set. And you may want to include the validators.

You could do that by having `validateEmail` and `validatePhone` return a boolean and then you can do

```js
submitForm(e) {
  const isValid =
    this.contact.firstName &&
    this.contact.lastName &&
    this.contact.email &&
    this.contact.phone &&
    this.validateEmail(this.contact.email) &&
    this.validatePhone(this.contact.phone);
  if (!isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
},
```

---

### update

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
      now: new Date().toISOString(),
      isSubmitted: false,
      msg: [],
      contact: {
        firstName: "##firstname##",
        lastName: "##lastname##",
        email: "##email##",
        phone: "##phone##",
        address: "##address##",
        city: "##city##",
        state: "##state##",
        zip: "##zip##",
        checked: false,
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    contact: {
      handler(newContact) {
        this.validateEmail(newContact.email);
        this.validatePhone(newContact.phone);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(e) {
      const isValid =
        this.contact.firstName &&
        this.contact.lastName &&
        this.contact.email &&
        this.contact.phone && 
        this.validateEmail(this.contact.email) &&
        this.validatePhone(this.contact.phone);
      console.log(isValid)
      if (!isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    validateEmail(value) {
      if (
        /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20})$/.test(
          value
        )
      ) {
        this.msg["email"] = "";
        return true
      } else {
        this.msg["email"] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        return false;
      }
    },
    validatePhone(value) {
      if (
        /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im.test(
          value
        )
      ) {
        this.msg["phone"] = "";
        return true
      } else {
        this.msg["phone"] = "Please enter a valid, 10 digit phone number.";
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form name="mainForm" @submit="submitForm" method="post">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>First Name*</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstname"
          v-model="contact.firstName"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last Name*</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastname"
          v-model="contact.lastName"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Email Address *</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" v-model="contact.email" required />
        <small v-if="msg.email">{{msg.email}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Phone*</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" v-model="contact.phone" required />
        <small v-if="msg.phone">{{msg.phone}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <button type="submit">
        <strong>Download</strong>
      </button></a
    >

    <div>
      <small>
        <em>* Denotes a required field.</em>
      </small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This mostly fixed it! However the form is now not submitting at all when the fields all have correct inputs.

Comment: updated with working code, seems to work just fine. Although you might want to avoid wrapping `<button>` with an `<a>`. Even the use of `<form>` tag is questionable in the context of a Vue app, but it seems like it's a progressive enhancement, not a SPA.

Comment: working as expected now! Thank you so much. Looks like it was that piece of logic in my validate methods I was missing. Thank you for the additional tips...you are correct in that it's a progressive enhancement. We are creating simple landing pages and do not need much componentization (if any). Just easy-to-write JavaScript. Thanks again!